# angularjs Factory error for ReST call

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angular-factory

I am new with AngularJs and I am trying to write a factory with ngResource to make a Rest call

here are my codes

factory

```
'use strict';

angular.module('restPracticeApp')
  .factory('myFactory',['$resource', function () {


    console.log('hi from factory')
  function myFactory($resource) {
    var myUrl = 'api/theUrl';

  return $resource(myUrl,{} , {
      'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
      'get': { method: 'GET'}
        });  

  }
  }]);
```

Controller :

```
'use strict';


angular.module('restPracticeApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$http','myFactory' ,
    function ($scope,$resource,$http,myFactory) {

        $scope.theLink = theLink;

        function theLink(theName) {
            $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: "http://localhost:9000/api/theUrl",
                    data: $scope.theName
            })
            .then(
                function successCallback(response) {

                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.result=response;
                },
                function errorCallback(response) {

                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.result=response;
              });
        }
  }]);
```

and in Html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="theName">
<button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="theLink(theName)">yo</button>
```

I am trying returning in the factory but its still saying "**Provider 'myFactory' must return a value from $get factory method."**

Please Help me out. I will really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
factory("myFactory",function($resource){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getResources = $resource('api/theUrl', {}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
    return factory;
})
```

Controller example about how to receive factory data:

```
.controller("AboutCtrl",function($scope,$resource,$http,myFactory){

    $scope.factorydata = myFactory.getResources.query();
    $scope.factorydata.$promise.then(function(data) {
        //something you want to do
    })
})
```

Comment: This code works, your url could have an issue. With a similar factory i've received json objects and get the data in different controllers.

Comment: Or you can tell me your error message  for more help